# Limiting Bandwidth of Download with cURL

Tags: php, curl, download

I have been trying to limit the bandwidth with PHP. I can't get the download rate to be limited with PHP.

Can you please help here?

```
function total_filesize($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD,12); //ITS NOT WORKING! 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.11) ".
            "Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);


    $chStore = curl_exec($ch);
    $chError = curl_error($ch);
    $chInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $size = $chInfo['download_content_length'];
}

function __define_url($url) {
    $basename = basename($url);
    Define('filename',$basename);
    $define_file_size = total_filesize($url);
    Define('filesizes',$define_file_size);
}

function _download_file($url_file) { 
    __define_url($url_file);

    // $range = "50000-60000";
    $filesize = filesizes;
    $file = filename; 
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"'); 
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header("Content-Length: $filesize");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"$url_file");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    //  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE,$range);

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
_download_file('http://rarlabs.com/rar/wrar393.exe');
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE.html) is the option you want.

Added in curl 7.15.5. Present in PHP/CURL since **PHP 5.4.0**

Comment: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51815 It was added just recently and is not present in any production releases. But still correct answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD` **informs** you of the download speed; it's not an option you can set. That said, if it were an option, you'd be setting it in the wrong place (in the part where you make a HEAD request to obtain the file size, – which by the way, is unnecessary, but that's irrelevant here – and not where you actually download the file).

You can do it with PHP streams, where you would loop and either retrieve/send more data or wait according to your limit, but I don't think there's a way to exchange a curl resource for a PHP stream. Your only alternative may be using the [http wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) instead.

You could also try `CURLOPT_FILE` and save the file to a "php://temp" stream, and then read from it, but I'm not sure it would work.

Answer (score -1):

I would limit the bandwidth via the server, e.g. IIS or Apache.

Comment: If I needed to do it, I'd do it on the operating system or network - but in god's name....why? I'd agree it makes sense for testing, but in production the bandwidth slows down **your** server as well as the client.