# Set a global PHP-CURL Upload & Download Speed limit?

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, php-curl

I use CURL in several individual PHP scripts to download / upload files, is there a way to set a GLOBAL (not per-curl-handle) UL / DL Rate Speed Limit?

Unfortunately, you can only set a speed limit for the single session at CURL, but that's not dynamic.

As a server OS Ubuntu is used, is there an alternative way to limit CURL processes differently?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting Bandwidth of Download with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066732/limiting-bandwidth-of-download-with-curl)

Comment: @FabianSchöner wrong, that will set a per-curl-handle bandwidth limit, not a system-global bandwidth limit.

Comment: can you guys stop marking this as a duplicate? this is NOT a duplicate, the question proposed as a duplicate is about how to limit the bandwidth on a single curl handle, not how to set a system/process-global rate.

Answer (score 0):

curl/libcurl doesn't have any feature to share a bandwidth limit across curl_easy handles, much less across different processes. i propose a curl daemon to enforce bandwidth limits instead. with the client looking something like

```
class curl_daemon_response{
    public $stdout;
    public $stderr;
}
function curl_daemon(array $curl_options):curl_daemon_response{
    $from_big_uint64_t=function(string $i): int {
        $arr = unpack ( 'Juint64_t', $i );
        return $arr ['uint64_t'];
    };
    $to_big_uint64_t=function(int $i): string {
        return pack ( 'J', $i );
    };
    $conn = stream_socket_client("unix:///var/run/curl_daemon", $errno, $errstr, 3);
    if (!$conn) {
        throw new \RuntimeError("failed to connect to /var/run/curl_daemon! $errstr ($errno)");
    }
    stream_set_blocking($conn,true);
    $curl_options=serialize($curl_options);
    fwrite($conn,$to_big_uint64_t(strlen($curl_options)).$curl_options);
    $stdoutLen=$from_big_uint64_t(fread($conn,8));
    $stdout=fread($conn,$stdoutLen);
    $stderrLen=$from_big_uint64_t(fread($conn,8));
    $stderr=fread($conn,$stderrLen);
    $ret=new curl_daemon_response();
    $ret->stdout=$stdout;
    $ret->stderr=$stderr;
    fclose($conn);
    return $ret;
}
```

and the daemon looking something like

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
const MAX_DOWNLOAD_SPEED=1000*1024; // 1000 kilobytes
const MINIMUM_DOWNLOAD_SPEED=100; // 100 bytes per second,
class Client{
    public $id;
    public $socket;
    public $curl;
    public $arguments;
    public $stdout;
    public $stderr;
}
$clients=[];
$mh=curl_multi_init();
$srv = stream_socket_server("unix:///var/run/curl_daemon", $errno, $errstr);
if (!$srv) {
  throw new \RuntimeError("failed to create unix socket /var/run/curl_daemon! $errstr ($errno)");
}
stream_set_blocking($srv,false);
while(true){
    getNewClients();
    $cc=count($clients);
    if(!$cc){
        sleep(1); // nothing to do.
        continue;
    }
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    if($running!==$cc){
        // at least 1 of the curls finished!
        while(false!==($info=curl_multi_info_read($mh))){
            $key=curl_getinfo($info['handle'],CURLINFO_PRIVATE);
            curl_multi_remove_handle($mh,$clients[$key]->curl);
            curl_close($clients[$key]->curl);
            $stdout=file_get_contents(stream_get_meta_data($clients[$key]->stdout)['uri']); // https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268
            fclose($clients[$key]->stdout);
            $stderr=file_get_contents(stream_get_meta_data($clients[$key]->stderr)['uri']); // https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268
            fclose($clients[$key]->stderr);
            $sock=$clients[$key]->socket;
            fwrite($sock,to_big_uint64_t(strlen($stdout)).$stdout.to_big_uint64_t(strlen($stderr)).$stderr);
            fclose($sock);
            echo "finished request #{$key}!\n";
            unset($clients[$key],$key,$stdout,$stderr,$sock);
        }
        updateSpeed();
    }
    curl_multi_select($mh);
}

function updateSpeed(){
    global $clients;
    static $old_speed=-1;
    if(empty($clients)){
        return;
    }
    $clientsn=count($clients);
    $per_handle_speed=MAX(MINIMUM_DOWNLOAD_SPEED,(MAX_DOWNLOAD_SPEED/$clientsn));
    if($per_handle_speed===$old_speed){
        return;
    }
    $old_speed=$per_handle_speed;
    echo "new per handle speed: {$per_handle_speed} - clients: {$clientsn}\n";
    foreach($clients as $client){
        /** @var Client $client */
        curl_setopt($client->curl,CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE,$per_hande_speed);
    }
}


function getNewClients(){
    global $clients,$srv,$mh;
    static $counter=-1;
    $newClients=false;
    while(false!==($new=stream_socket_accept($srv,0))){
        ++$counter;
        $newClients=true;
        echo "new client! request #{$counter}\n";
        stream_set_blocking($new,true);
        $tmp=new Client();
        $tmp->id=$counter;
        $tmp->socket=$new;
        $tmp->curl=curl_init();
        $tmp->stdout=tmpfile();
        $tmp->stderr=tmpfile();
        $size=from_big_uint64_t(fread($new,8));
        $arguments=fread($new,$size);
        $arguments=unserialize($arguments);
        assert(is_array($arguments));
        $tmp->arguments=$arguments;
        curl_setopt_array($tmp->curl,$arguments);
        curl_setopt_array($tmp->curl,array(
            CURLOPT_FILE=>$tmp->stdout,
            CURLOPT_STDERR=>$tmp->stderr,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,
            CURLOPT_PRIVATE=>$counter
        ));
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$tmp->curl);
    }
    if($newClients){
        updateSpeed();
    }
}

function from_big_uint64_t(string $i): int {
    $arr = unpack ( 'Juint64_t', $i );
    return $arr ['uint64_t'];
}
function to_big_uint64_t(int $i): string {
    return pack ( 'J', $i );
}
```

note: this is completely untested code, because my development environment died literally a couple of hours ago, and i wrote all this in notepad++. (my dev env won't boot at all, it's a VM, not sure wtf happened, but haven't fixed it yet )

also, the code is not at all optimized for large file transfers, if you need to support big file transfers this way (sizes you don't want packed up in ram, like gigabytes+), then modify the daemon to return filepaths instead of writing all the data over an unix socket.